# Telerik radgrid couldn't remove empty rows

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik-grid

IN the telerik radgrid, I want to delete the 4th row of the grid but it's not working. It throws an error `Argument out of exception`.

I got 4 rows and the first 2 rows has some values...so i want to delete the other 2 rows which are empty but it's not working.

Try 1:

```
radGridView2.Rows.Remove(radGridView2.Rows[3]);
```

Try 2:

```
radGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(3);
```

The radgrid code:

```
private const int Test = 4;
private void SetDataGridView()
        {


            for (var rowCount = 0; rowCount < Test; rowCount++)
            {
                radGridView1.Rows.Add(string.Empty); 


            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove it from the datasource and then call databind in order to bind wit new DataSource.

Delete on DataTable

```
YourDataTable.Rows.Remove(YourRow);
```

So you can create with

```
int count = YourControl.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
{
    if (condition) //You can adjust your condition, for example i == 0
    { 
       YourControl.DeleteRow(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using any data source.

Comment: i updaeted my post with  DeleteRow

Comment: in the control place, i put `radGridView2` it's not accepting. it shows me an error; Could you please tell me what is the condition. Thank you

Comment: condition is your functionnal need, you can for example removre the row in position index == 0 or another value,

Comment: try wth if(i ==3 ), replace this condition  : if (radGridView2.Rows[3])

Answer (score 0):

right before the line that remove the row to be execute, add a watch to see how many rows the grid have. 
I think your code do more things thats not shown in the snippet of this question.

Answer (score 0):

remove all rows from radgrid in winform c#

```
for (int totalrow = 0; totalrow < radGridView1.Rows.Count; totalrow++)
{
     radGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
     totalrow--;
}
```